# ERROR 1064 (42000) on mysql when creating a table

Tags: mariadb

```
MariaDB [(none)]>
MariaDB [(none)]> create database isathub
    -> CREATE TABLE `tab_access` (
    -> `id` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    -> `isApp` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
    -> `datetime` DATETIME NOT NULL,
    -> `lat` VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT NULL,
    -> `long` VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT NULL,
    -> `category` VARCHAR(250) DEFAULT NULL,
    -> `name` VARCHAR(250) DEFAULT NULL,
    -> `url` VARCHAR(250) DEFAULT NULL,
    -> `os` VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT NULL,
    -> `imei` VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT NULL,
    -> `apn` VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT NULL,
    -> PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
    ->
    -> ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

I am getting the error:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'CREATE TABLE `tab_access` (
`id` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`isAp' at line 2
```

I Don't know what it wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your create table statement looks fine, but you didn't put a semicolon after:

```
create database isathub
```

So it didn't execute that statement, and thinks the create table statement is part of the create database statement.

Answer (score 0):

syntax:
`create database database_name;`

now you can create table

```
create table 'table_name'();
```